# javascript async/await not working

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have a specific case where I need to wait for a async calls result before
continuing. I am using the async/await keywords, but not having any luck.
Any help appreciated.

This is my attempt to try getting it to work, the numbers should be in numerical order.

```js
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function demo() {
  document.writeln('2...');
  await sleep(2000);
  document.writeln('3...');
}

document.writeln('1...');
demo();
document.writeln('4.');
```

Comment: Why exactly do you think they should be in numerical order? `3` comes last, because that’s the last thing that gets executed after the Promise function. Do you expect `1...2...3...4.` to be displayed at the very end? Then don’t use `document.writeln`. Use standard DOM APIs instead.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should use `.then()` after [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

```js
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function demo() {
  document.writeln('2...');
  await sleep(2000);
  document.writeln('3...');
}

document.writeln('1...');
demo().then(() => {
    document.writeln('4.');
});
```

Answer (score 32):

The async function will return a `Promise`, so you need to await the call to `demo`

```js
const sleep = (ms) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))

const demo = async() => {
  console.log('2...')
  await sleep(2000)
  console.log('3...')
}

const blah = async() => {
  console.log('1...')
  await demo()
  console.log('4.')
}

blah()
```